# Why is this WifiInfo sometimes null on android?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I have a BroadcastReceiver that subscribes to `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE` events in the manifest.

In my broadcast receiver, I want to extract the SSID of the network I am connected to, then do something with it. Here is my code:

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectionReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my connection receiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    Log.d("WFC", "CONNECTIVITY CHANGE: " + intent.getAction() + " state: " + networkInfo.getState().toString());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) && networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

          WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
          if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.w("WFC", "wifi info is null");
            return;
          }

          String rawSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
          // do stuff here
    }
}
```

This works fine on my phone (galaxy nexus running 4.2), but I've seen issues on some other phones (one running 2.3.6, another running 4.0.4), where the wifiInfo object retrieved from the intent is always `null`.

This means my receiver cannot continue with execution, so it logs this fact, then exits every time.

I'm kind of at a loss as to why this might be the case as I'm explicitly checking that the phone is connected to a network. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

instead of

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
```

where `wifiManager` is the `WifiManager` instance obtained using:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Comment: This yields `wifiInfo.getSSID() // # "<unknown ssid>"` most of the time.